# Creating a blueprint bean from an inner class

Tags: java, spring, blueprint-osgi

In Spring I can create a bean from an inner class thus:

```
<bean id="exampleInnerBean" class="my.package.Class$InnerClass" />
```

But in Blueprint this doesn't work, I get a SAXParseException:

```
cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: 'my.package.Class$InnerClass' is not a valid value for 'NCName'.
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong / what syntax I should be using / if this is even possible?

If it helps / matters, I'm installing a bundle containing the above bean into JBoss Fuse 6.0.0.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was able to just use the same syntax as in Java:

```
<bean id="exampleInnerBean" class="my.package.Clazz.InnerClass" />
```

The only problem I faced was because I am using the **Maven Bundle plugin**... the plugin assumed that `my.package.Clazz` was a package and therefore added it to the list of imported packages for my bundle. This is simply fixed by adding the following to the plugin `<configuration><instructions>` tag in the POM:

```
 <Import-Package>!my.package.Clazz,*</Import-Package>
```

This stops the plugin adding my.package.Clazz to the list of imported packages for my bundle and everything just works.